# Comparing date fields of different tables with same table structure in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

For 1 of our database comparison tool development, I was trying following sql, but its not showing appropriate results.

```
select BA_NO 
from BL_invoice_DT_mock 
where recon_ind = 'B'  and (PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_S <>  PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_T)
```

`BL_invoice_DT_mock` table has 2 fields to store `PRD_CVRG_END_DATE` from source and target respectively.

Though, there is BA_NO which has `PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_S`  as `NULL` and `PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_T` as '3/4/2014'

But still above sql is not showing this `BA_NO` in output.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that in Oracle `DATE` also contains a time part!

Answer (score 0):

try NVL:

```
select BA_NO 
from BL_invoice_DT_mock 
where recon_ind = 'B'  and (NVL(PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_S,'1900-01-01') <>  NVL(PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_T,'1900-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thanks Jayvee , but isnull is not working.Its saying ISNULL is invalid identifier. Any other alternative :(

Comment: what are  PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_S and PRD_CVRG_END_DATE_T data types?

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Comment: I am running on oracle 9i

Comment: oh, it's the wrong tagged then... you need NVL instead of ISNULL